# Android Print Service

Tags: android, printing, android-print-framework

I am working on a POS app. I need to print the receipt which will be shown in an activity. how to do this? What is the procedure to print data in a activity? I am new to android and print functions.

Comment: Is this in a pdf format?

Comment: Any format is fine. I just need to print an activity basically a scroll view activity as this is a receipt. @Ankita